# Ошибка TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, sqlite3

Я смотря видео ютубера Фсоки попытался создать экономического бота, Написал весть код и тут выходит эта ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Script\bot\botyara.py", line 82, in __balance
    description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Вод (Как я считаю) нужный отрывок кода:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT,
        server_id INT
    )""")
 
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
        role_id INT,
        id INT,
        cost BIGINT
    )""")
 
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id})")
            else:
                pass
 
    connection.commit()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, {member.guild.id})")
        connection.commit()
    else:
        pass

@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash'])
async def __balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
        
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя {member} составляет {cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:"""
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в том, что не существует ctx.author.id, есть ctx.message.author.id.

Исправленный код.

```
@client.command(aliases = ['balance', 'cash'])
async def __balance(ctx, member:  discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        balance = cursor.execute("""SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}""".format(ctx.message.author.id)).fetchone()[0]
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        description=f"Баланс пользователя **{ctx.message.author}** составляет ** {balance}:leaves:**"))        
    else:
        balance = cursor.execute("""SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}""".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        description = f"Баланс пользователя {member} составляет {balance} :leaves:"))
```

Comment: Не работает, выдаёт данную ошибку
```
Ignoring exception in command __balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Script\bot\botyara.py", line 81, in __balance
    balance = cursor.execute("""SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}""".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Понял в чём ошибка, переписываю ответ